# SQL Server - combine results of two SELECT statements using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, outer-join

I need to combine the results of two SQL queries in SQL Server using a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

query 1:

```
SELECT     dbo.saitem.itm_id, dbo.saitem.itm_num, dbo.saitemcls.cde_id
FROM         dbo.saitem INNER JOIN
                      dbo.saitemcls ON dbo.saitem.itm_id = dbo.saitemcls.itm_id
WHERE     (dbo.saitemcls.cde_id = 109)
```

query 2:

```
SELECT     dbo.sacatalog.cat_name, dbo.sacatalogitem.itm_id
FROM         dbo.sacatalogitem INNER JOIN
                      dbo.sacatalog ON dbo.sacatalogitem.cat_id = dbo.sacatalog.cat_id
WHERE     (dbo.sacatalog.cat_name = 'CATALOG1')
```

I need to return dbo.saitem.itm_id and dbo.saitem.itm_num from query 1, where dbo.saitem.itm_id is not in query 2, matching on dbo.saitem.itm_id (query 1) and  dbo.sacatalogitem.itm_id (query 2).

The SQL Server server is 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-select for this:

```
select
    i.itm_id, 
    i.itm_num
from
    dbo.saitem i
        inner join
    dbo.saitemcls c
        on i.itm_id = c.itm_id
where
    c.cde_id = 109 and
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            dbo.sacatalogitem ci 
                inner join
            dbo.sacatalog s
                on ci.cat_id = s.cat_id
        where
            s.cat_name = 'CATALOG1' and
            i.itm_id = ci.itm_id -- note this refers to the outer query
    );
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the 'x'?

Comment: You have to select something. But as we're only checking for the existence of rows it doesn't matter what you select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT joins and check for NULL, like this:

```
SELECT dbo.saitem.itm_id, dbo.saitem.itm_num, dbo.saitemcls.cde_id
FROM dbo.saitem 
JOIN dbo.saitemcls ON dbo.saitem.itm_id = dbo.saitemcls.itm_id AND dbo.saitemcls.cde_id = 109
LEFT JOIN dbo.sacatalogitem ON dbo.saitem.itm_id = dbo.sacatalogitem.itm_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.sacatalog ON dbo.sacatalogitem.cat_id = dbo.sacatalog.cat_id AND dbo.sacatalog.cat_name = 'CATALOG1'
WHERE dbo.sacatalog.cat_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct?  The match needs to be on itm_id, not cat_ID.

Comment: Might you end up with repeated data using this approach?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak - This was from your example, you have to join catalog from logitem to check that it is in cat_name 'CATALOG1'

Comment: @Laurence Don't see how -- I'm only returning things that are null, I guess if sacatalogitem has multiple entries for items, but I would  not expect a DB to be designed this way.

Comment: @Hogan Your query doesn't work.  It returns 88,000+ items, which is essentially every item in the database.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak - Sounds like a typo, did you `dbo.saitemcls.cde_id = 109`?

Comment: @Hogan I copied your query in verbatim and ran it.  I double-checked, and it still returns every item.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak - Can't say, unless every item is the correct result.  Do you have any items linked to CATALOG1

Comment: @Hogan Yes, but not all of them.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak this returns items that are NOT linked... as you asked for.  I guess that is a lot of item.s